# find certain tag using loop in PHP

Tags: php, dom

Says I've a variable $content that its ouput will be

```
<div>
<p>text</p>
<p>text more</p>
<img src="google.jpg"/>
<img src=""/>
<img src=""/>
</div>
```

if I do echo $content, I want to get the first img URL without echo anything out of the screen. How should I do?

Comment: You want to echo `$content`, but you don't want an output ?!

Comment: @BhavikShah I don't even know what to do

Comment: @Alexbecker Use Google. Find some relevant solution. If that is not working, then you come here and post the code, show your efforts and look for help from community.

Comment: @Rizier123 $content is collection of many element, I just want the first img's url

Comment: @BhavikShah I've tried. Please help.

Comment: @Alexbecker if you have tried anything, you should include the codes in your question too.

Comment: @Ghost please write some code to guide me at least :(

Comment: @Alexbecker research about HTML parsers. use PHP's `DOMDocument`

Comment: `preg_match_all("/.*<img.*?src=(\"|\')(.*?)(\"|\')/i", $output, $output_array);
if(isset($output_array[2][0]))
    echo $output_array[2][0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `HTML parsing`

```
//your sample data
$content = '<div><p>text</p><p>text more</p><img src="google.jpg"/><img src=""/><img src=""/></div>'

//create object
$doc = new DOMDocument();

//load html from string
$doc->loadHTML($content);

//get all images
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

//loop through all images
foreach ($images as $image) {

  //print image path
  echo $image->getAttribute('src');

  //this is necessary to print only first image path
  //if you want path of all images, simply remove break statement
  break;
}
```

Check [**`this`**](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html) and [**`this`**](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) for more reference

Comment: what is the benefit of this versus @rizer's regex approaches?